# Can't find an element Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-chromedriver

http://pastebin.com/pAyr9i6L - here is a part of html code of the page

I want to extract "202,06 pуб." string. How to do it using Selenium for Python? I could use the get_attribute function to do it, but the string isn't identified in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the element *by id* and get the `.text` property value:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("header_wallet_balance").text
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Sadly I don't have enough points to upvote

Answer (score 2):

Attempt to conceive some code before asking, it conveys people that you are trying hard!

For this code sample it's quite simple, ids are unique for elements so it's a good way to go on about it
xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='header_wallet_balance']").text
```

id

```
driver.find_element_by_id('header_wallet_balance').text
```

Comment: 1. This would result into a syntax error - no closing `)` 2. There is no `get_element_by_xpath` method in Python selenium bindings. 3. Why use the "by xpath" if there is a simpler and faster "by id" technique?

Comment: Thank you. Well, I haven't found the 'text' property in the docs  , I wil try harder next time :)

Comment: Please consider accepting @alecxe answer by clicking the green checkmark on the left, it's concise and was the quickest ;)